# Logstash - grok renaming field name

Tags: logstash-grok

Here is an exmple of event message:

```
{
"timestamp":"2016-03-29T22:35:44.770750-0400",
"flow_id":45385792,
"in_iface":"eth1",
"event_type":"alert",
"src_ip":"3.3.3.8",
"src_port":21,
"dest_ip":"2.2.2.2",
"dest_port":52934,
"proto":"TCP",
"alert":{
    "action":"allowed",
    "gid":1,
    "signature_id":4027,
    "rev":0,
    "signature":"FTP Successful Login",
    "category":"",
    "severity":3
    },
"payload":"MjU3ICIvaG9tZS9uZXd1c2VyIg0K",
"payload_printable":"257 newuser",
"stream":0,
"packet":"AFBWo0NoAFBWoxZWCABFAABJKDpAAEAGCGcDAwMIAgICAgAVzsbd4MhqOBOjfoAYAOMYcwAAAQEIChHN4EQHnwugMjU3ICIvaG9tZS9uZXd1c2VyIg0K"
}


input 
    beats 
        port => 5044
        codec => json
        type => "SuricataIDPS"
```

My Logstash config file is the following:

```
output 
    elasticsearch 
        hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
        sniffing => true
        manage_template => false
        index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
        #document_type => "%{[@metadata][type]}"
```

I'd like to be able to rename the field alert.signature,

How can I do so?... Seems that it does not recognize that field...

Thanks for your help!

Efrat

Answer (score 5):

You  have to define  `mutate`  filter within `filter` stanza:

```
filter {

        mutate {
                rename =>  [ "[alert][signature]", "[alert][signature_renamed]"  ]
        }
}
```